# How many powers of a prime factor in a number

Tags: prime-numbers, exponentiation, prime-factorization, perfect-powers

> I have a number $K$ that can be expressed as $$K = a^pb^qc^r$$ where each of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are prime numbers. Given $K$ and $a$, how do I find out the value of $p$?

I initially thought of taking the log of $K$ with $a$ as the base but that would return a number $m$, such that $a^m$ is less than (or equal in case $q$ and $r$ are both zero) and is not necessarily a divisor of $K$. I have a feeling the solution is straight forward but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be great.

**EDIT**

The other thing I thought of was repeated division by the prime until the division returns a remainder. But is there a single step solution?

Comment: The "straight forward" method, though tedious, is to repeatedly divide K by a until the quotient is no longer a multiple of a.  For example, 108 is divisible by the prime number 3.  To determine what the power of 3 is, divide 108 by 3 go get 36, divide 36 by 3 to get 12, and divide 12 by 3 to get 4.  4 is not a multiple of 3 and we divided by 3 three times.  So 108= 3^3 times 4.

Comment: @user247327 Sorry, was just adding that to the question. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)  ?  I know PARI/GP uses valuation.

Comment: one way to cut the steps of the straight forward method is divide by consecutively increasing powers as you go then you can bound p between two triangular numbers.

Comment: You might take a look at the Wikipedia entry on integer relation algorithms, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm and the links therein.  But I don't think you'll find a single-step solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an answer to the final OP's question:

> The other thing I thought of was repeated division by the prime until the division returns a remainder. But is there a single step solution?

If you are trying to represent that function in a single step for an specific theoretical purpose, well you can do it. It is not useful, but theoretically correct ([in the style of G.H.Hardy's 'A formula for the prime factors of any number'](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=kk-SCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=g.h.%20hardy%20%22a%20formula%20for%20the%20prime%20factors%20of%20any%20number%22%20messenger%20of%20mathematics%2035&source=bl&ots=L4hZeSZbH7&sig=hvlEE0MrJu35RNLSbJvj_cwBg1I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkn8revbXVAhXGT7wKHZMxB1IQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=g.h.%20hardy%20%22a%20formula%20for%20the%20prime%20factors%20of%20any%20number%22%20messenger%20of%20mathematics%2035&f=false)). It is just a curiosity:

> $p=\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} (1-\lceil{\frac{K}{a^t}-\lfloor\frac{K}{a^t}\rfloor}\rceil)$

The expression $\lceil{\frac{K}{a^t}-\lfloor\frac{K}{a^t}\rfloor}\rceil$ will be $0$ if $a^t$ is a divisor of $K$ (no decimals), and $1$ if $a^t$ is not a divisor of $K$ because there are decimals in the division, so the result is a number in the interval $(0,1)$, and the ceil of such decimal number will be always $1$.

For that reason, only the $t$ exponents that make $a^t$ a divisor of $K$ will make the expression $$(1-\lceil{\frac{K}{a^t}-\lfloor\frac{K}{a^t}\rfloor}\rceil)=(1-0)=1$$ ...equal to $1$. So counting the $1$'s we will obtain the value of $p$.

E.g.:

$24=2^3 \cdot 3$

$K=24, a=2$

> $p=\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} (1-\lceil{\frac{24}{2^t}-\lfloor\frac{24}{2^t}\rfloor}\rceil)= 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 \cdots = 3$